# Center ggplot2 output image around x-axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot below shows some data I collected. It was plotted and saved using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(gate, (aes(V, I))) +
  geom_line()

ggsave("filename.png", width = 15, height = 7, units = "cm")
```

Is there a way to center the output image of the plot around the x-axis label? With that I mean that in my plot the x-label should be the center of the output picture, not the center of the plot region. (e.g. by adding whitespace to the right site of the plot)

[image]

Comment: When you include a reproducible example, this will be on topic on [SO].  However, you will also need to explain what you mean by "center the plot," because this plot already centers the x-axis label relative to the plot region.

Comment: @whuber Oh yes, I should have posted to StackOverflow. Thank you.